# How to use two tables data in a view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two tables, first table is about topic name and second table shows sub-topics. I want to show from first table topic name then search their corresponding sub-topic and show it in view and so on till topic names are found in first table. But the problem is i can only get one table data in view i.e. main topic table. I have no idea how to get full data of both table and use it.

> Database Structure:

[image]

> Model:

```
<?php 

    class Topics_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
        {
              parent::__construct();
        }

    function get_all_topics()
    {
       $this->load->database();
       $this->db->select("*");
       $this->db->from("topics");
       $query=$this->db->get();
       return $query->result();
    }
    }
```

?>

> Controller :

```
<?php

class drag_drop_course_material extends CI_Controller {

  function drag_drop_course_material()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   function index()
    {
     $this->load->model('topics_model');
     $data['query']=$this->topics_model->get_all_topics();
     $this->load->helper('url');
     $this->load->view('drag_drop_course_material', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

View:

```
 <?php
    foreach ($query as $row) {
 ?>
   <li>  $row->topic_name   </li>
 <? }  ?>
```

Required Output:

[image]

Comment: foreach topics, get the subtopics, store in array and loop in view.

Comment: Have you tried `mysql join`??

Comment: I think it can't be done by join.

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju Can u please tell me through example or give me a link for it.

Comment: please check this link, make sure you change database column names accordingly,http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff26d309b84b2c6d821136bd34b489c280c4f3ab

Comment: I think **mysql's group_concat()**  would be a one of the ways you can achieve result something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is perfect, your model is perfect just change your view:

In view:

```
        foreach ($query as $row) 
        { ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $row['topic_name'];?>
            <ul>
            <?php $this->db->where('sub_topic_id',$row['id'])
            $r = $this->db->get('subtopics');
            if($r->num_rows()>0)
            {
                foreach ($r -> result_array() as $row) {
                $data1[] = $row;
                }
            }
            foreach($data1 as $sub){?>
            //print <li><?php echo $sub['subtopic_name']?></li>
            <? }?>
          </ul>
        </li>
       <? }?>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. We do left join of both tables.

```
$CI->db->select('*');
$CI->db->from('topic');
$CI->db->join('sub-topics', 'topic.id = sub-topics.sub_topic_id', 'left');
$query = $CI->db->get();
$result =  $query->result();
```

You will get result in your model. return this result from model and access it in controller. Once you print return result in controller you will get idea that how to render it because you already did it above.

Comment: @user3653474 Please check that i have edited answer.

Comment: @DeepParekh As he have all the result . He can prepare custom arrays by indexing array with topic as key

Comment: @sandeepsure Thanks for your answer, but it is giving different output, my main topic will be displayed irrespective of whether it has subtopics or not.

Comment: @Deep Parekh In my model i am retrieving data from only one table so how can my model and controller are correct there is something missing.

Comment: @user3653474 You need to loop through each of the record and index it with the topic id.

Comment: @Deep Parekh So i have to retrieve code of my second table in view.

Comment: @DeepParekh You have made SQL query in loop which should be avoided.

Comment: @user3653474 Print the `$result` array and edit this answer and paste it. I will write the code that how you can print it.

Comment: yes you can fetch the records of subtopics in your view.